# Xcode update messed up Storyboard constraints

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints, updates

So I went into my Xcode project today and it wanted me to update it, so I did.

Now, on my initial view controller, there is a search Bar that is missing when I run the simulator.  Before the update, my constraints on the storyboard were all fine, and this search Bar was visible in the simulator.

Now, I can't see it in the simulator, and the constraints are still fine, with no warnings or errors, but I redid them anyway, to no avail.

Anyone else having this problem? Any idea how to fix this?  I am assuming it's the update.

Here's a picture of the storyboard vs the simulator:

Storyboard:

[image]

Search Bar constraints (no warnings):

[image]

Simulator:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly did you update?  Xcode or the swift version?

Comment: not sure, when I did it it was because xcode crashed, then when I clicked on it to reopen it wanted me to update it. It wasn't in the app store that I did it, if that helps.  I clicked on it, and it prompted me to update so I did

Comment: Try giving height constraint to search bar

Comment: That worked! Thanks!